# Treeview loses its focus in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a treeview in my WPF MVVM application. Also I have a textbox that displays the value of the treenode. Right now when I expand the treeview and select a node its value is fetched and displayed on the textbox.
Now I included a checkbox that displays the numbers that appear on the textbox as words.(For eg : 11 as one one). Once I click on the checkbox the treeview loses its focus. Both the expansion of treeview and selection is lost. Only when I click the node again the value is shown in the textbox as words. How can I fix that?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"   Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="150" SelectedValuePath="0" >
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />                           
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <TextBlock Text="Data" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

  <TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                 IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5,0" />

<CheckBox Content="View In Words" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding InWords}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @XAMLLover: sure . here its